# A is an open set and a close set prove that $ A = R^n$ or $A = \varnothing$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subseteq R^n$
 such that A is an open set and a close set

prove that $ A = R^n$ or $A = \varnothing$

Comment: Adding to Ians comment, it may help to look into path-connectednes as well.

Comment: Something to help you search: if a set is both open and closed then it is sometimes called clopen. A nonempty clopen subset of a topological space which contains no other clopen sets is called a connected component. A topological space is connected if it is a connected component of itself (i.e. the only clopen subsets are $\emptyset$ and the whole space). So your question can be phrased in more natural language as "is $\mathbb{R}^n$ connected?"

Comment: What is your definition of an open set in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Exactly - use the basic properties you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $A \subsetneq \Bbb R^n$ is non-empty and is both closed and open.

Consider any $a \in A$ and any $b \in \Bbb R^n \setminus A$.  Consider the line defined by the (continuous!) function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
f(t) = (1-t)a + t\,b
$$
Define $t_{max} = \sup\{t: f(t) \in A\}$. Is $f(t_{max})$ in $A$ or in $\Bbb R^n \setminus A$?  Remember, both $A$ *and* its complement are closed.

Or, for a more sophisticated argument: note that both $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(\Bbb R^n \setminus A)$ must be disjoint and open in $[0,1]$.  However, $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: **Note:** this proof can be extended to show that any path-connected set is connected